# Computing the Norm of a Vector in Parallel and Concurrently using Async/Futures

Tags: c++, asynchronous, concurrency

I am trying to calculate the 2-norm of a vector that is expected to be large using both recursion and async. This is what I have so far. I am getting the correct answer for the norm, but my program does not seem to have improved performance. In fact, computing the norm sequentially seems to be faster. Can someone take a look and see what I am doing incorrectly?

```
double rtn_worker(const Vector& x, unsigned long begin2, unsigned long end2, unsigned long level2){
  int begin = (int) begin2; 
  int end = (int) end2; 
  int level = (int) level2; 
  if(level == 0){
    double temp_partial = 0.0; 
    for(unsigned long i = begin; i <= end; ++i){   
      temp_partial += x(i)*x(i);
    }
    return temp_partial; 
  }
  else{
    return rtn_worker(x, begin, begin+(end-begin)/2, level-1)+rtn_worker(x, begin+(end-begin)/2+1, end, level-1); 
  }
}
double recursiveTwoNorm(const Vector& x, unsigned long levels){
  double sum = 0.0; 
  unsigned long end = x.numRows();
  std::future<double> partial = std::async(std::launch::deferred, rtn_worker, std::ref(x), 0, end-1, levels); 
  sum += partial.get(); 
  double norm = sqrt(sum); 
  return norm; 
}
```

A note: I have defined classes for Vector. Here, .numRows() is a private member function that returns the length of the vector.

Although I have used math stack exchange frequently, this is my first post in stack overflow. Any and all comments and critique are appreciated!

*I have implemented this using thread.h, but I would like to compare the performance with async.

Comment: sequential is always faster, parallelisation isn't a magic bullet of performance, often the opposite when threading overheads, context switching and locking ar e all taken into account.

Comment: @gbjbaanb: Where do you see parallelisation?

Comment: @MSalters where he used thread.h, but async is all about threading which is running using all the overheads associated with parallelisation, even if you're only running 1 thread at a time. That's what I meant, not that he's running many tasks at once.

Answer (score 0):

There's no point in `std::launch::deferred` if you're immediately going to call `.get()` on the resulting future. The whole point of deferring a calculation is that you don't need the result straight away.

Not that `std::launch::async` would have helped much either - you'd have one thread waiting for another.

The problem is that you're using `async` on the wrong level. `rtn_worker` calls itself twice. It would be efficient to run one of these invocations asynchronously. In this case, use `std::launch::deferred |`std::launch::async`to let the runtime choose, or use`level` to choose explicitly.